# Does Mat inherit from InputArray?

Tags: opencv

I've read the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#details) stating that `InputArray` and `Mat` can be used interchangeably.

But how do these two relate?

Is `InputArray` `Mat`'s superclass?

Comment: look at the source code, it is open source

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly you see such statement. It's a proxy class "designed solely for passing parameters" -- meaning it's a thin wrapper that allows OpenCV functions to take a number of different datatypes as input (`Mat`s, vectors, etc).